# Why Concordance index is increasing a lot when adding a non-significant variable?

Tags: python, regression, cox-regression, concordance-index

I'm testing some models using the Cox regression fitter and comparing concordance index between each other.

I can't quite understand why, adding one single variable that is not even significant (p-value > 0.005) in a model that has already 5 (all significant), the concordance index increases from 0.54 to 0.61?

Thanks a lot for your help (and sorry in advance if my question is silly for a lot of you).

Stefano

Comment: statistical significance doesn't mean much when describing model fit or predictive power. I wouldn't worry about this.

Comment: I know that it's normal to have accuracy going up when adding variables that are not significant (just because you are increasing the possibility of explaning extra variability in the data) but usually the increase is really tiny exactly because they are not explaining that much more....

Comment: It's more subtle. I can create a variable that has high prediction power, but if it also has very high variance, then it will not be significant (in the statistical sense).

Comment: Hey @Cam.Davidson.Pilon, based on your suggestion, I'm deep-diving on this and thanks for your answer. I've posted another question regarding the hazard function for survival model that you can find here...maybe you can help me (thanks in advance): [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68834662/find-local-maximum-for-lifelines-hazard-function)