# Find local maximum for lifelines hazard function

Tags: python, max, lifelines, hazard

I'm trying to find a method to **detect local maximum points** for hazard function (plotted using lifelines library).

Lifelines library gives you the ability to plot visually the hazard function ( plot.hazard() ) but - as said - it's only the visual representation of the funcion and not the function itself. This means that you can't, apparently, pass this function as an argument to methods (i.e: find_peaks from scipy.signals library).

I'm wondering if anyone has a solution to detect those, please find below how I've calculated my hazard function (plot on the far right where I've highlighted the local max):

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3,figsize=(18,8))

km.fit(duration, event_observed = event)
kap = km.plot_survival_function(ax=ax1,legend="")
kap.set_title("Kaplan-Meier",fontsize=15)

na.fit(duration, event_observed = event)

na1 = na.plot_cumulative_hazard(ax=ax2,legend="",color="green")
na1.set_title("Cumulative Hazard",fontsize=15)

bandwidth = 5
na2 = na.plot_hazard(ax=ax3,xlim=(0,200),ylim=(0,0.03),bandwidth=bandwidth,color="orange",legend="")
na2.set_title("Hazard Function",fontsize=15)
ax3.set_xlabel('timeline',fontsize = 10)
plt.grid(linestyle="-.", color='grey')
```

[image]

Thanks to anyone who will help me.

Stefano

Answer (score -1):

Something like `na.smoothed_hazard_(bandwidth)`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29619581)

Comment: @slideshowp2: Sure it does. It would be better with an explanation. But it’s clearly offering a proposed answer. We delete answers that make no attempt to solve the problem—such as follow-up questions—or rely exclusively on a link. This one might be a low-quality answer, but that’s a reason to downvote it, not delete it ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)).

Comment: This should probably just be edited to look more like an answer than a question...

Comment: @Cam.Davidson.Pilon, thanks! seems I can get a df containing the y for each x of the function. the array has a shape of (50,1) but find_peaks accept only 1 dimensional array, do you know how to transform it to a (50,0) shape to feed find_peaks method?